# Django loading mysql data into template correctly

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to django and I'm trying to get display a list of buildings and sort them alphabetically, then load it into an html document. Is there something that I am not doing correctly?

below is models.py

```
class Class(models.Model):
    building = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'class'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.building
```

below is views.py

```
views.py

def index(request):
    buildinglist = Class.objects.all().order_by('building')
    c = {'buildinglist': buildinglist}
    t = loader.get_template('index.html')
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

below is index.html

```
index.html

{% block content%}
<h3>Buildings:</h3>
<ul>
    {% for building in buildinglist %}
        <li>
            <a href='www.{% building %}.com'>
                            # ex. www.searstower.com
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Can you guys point me in the right direction?
Thank you in advance guys! I appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`render()` expects that its first argument is the request.  [Take a look at the documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render).  Try:

```
return render_to_response('index.html',
                          c,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: thanks it loaded! but is there a reason why my content isn't loaded from my database?